# Coordinates of specific points on a triangle, given the triangles coordinates

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm working on a programing project. For that project I have a triangle with points $A,B,C$, where $A(a_1,a_2,a_3);B(b_1,b_2,b_3);C(c_1,c_2,c_3)$. Given the coordinates of the points $A,B$ and $C$, I want to find the coordinates of the orthocenter, circumcenter,incenter and the points where the perpendicular bisectors ,altitudes and  angle bisectors meet with the $AB,BC,CA$. I believe there are formulas for each of these things. I tried looking online, but I couldn't find anything, so I'm asking you - Are there formulas for these things, and if so what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are formulas, but it is probably easier to derive them than to find them online.  The derivations become much easier if you work with vectors and take point $A$ to be $(0,0,0)$ (that is, translating by subtracting (a_1, a_2, a_3)$ from all of the points until the very end when you add it back.

Let's take the meeting points of the altitudes with the sides first, and look for point $P$ where the altitude from $C$ meets $AB$ (the other two cases are easy switches of $A$, $B$ and $C$ once you know that case).  Let $AB = \vec{b}$ and $AC = \vec{c}$ and $AP = \vec{p}$.
Then because $P$ is on (extended) line $AB$, 
$$
\vec{p} = k\vec{b}
$$
for some scalar $k$. And since $CP \perp AP$,
$$
\vec{c}-\vec{p} \perp \vec{b} \rightarrow
 (\vec{c} - k\vec{b})\cdot \vec{b} = 0 \rightarrow
 k = \frac{\vec{c}\cdot \vec{b}}{|b|^2} =
\frac{b_1 c_1 + b_2 c_2 + b_3 c_3}{b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2}
$$
$$\vec{p} = \frac{\vec{c}\cdot \vec{b}}{|b|^2}\vec{b} 
= \frac{b_1 c_1 + b_2 c_2 + b_3 c_3}{b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2}\left( b_1, b_2, b_3\right)
$$
Translating back the the original coordinates this gives
$$
\left( a_1 + k (b_1-a_1),  a_2 + k (b_2-a_2), a_2 + k (b_2-a_2) \right)
$$ with
$$ 
k=\frac{(b_1-a_1) (c_1-a_1) + (b_2-a_2) (c_2-a_2) + (b_3-a_3) (c_3-a_3)}{(b_1-a_1)^2 + (b_2-a_2)^2 + (b_3-a_3)^2}
$$
(You can see how to do the translation to original coordinates from this; from here forward I will only show the work in the coordinates with $A$ at the origin.)

As long as we are working with altitudes, let's do the orthocenter next:  We start with $Q$, the foot of the altitude on $AC$ which by the same reasoning as above is at
$$
\vec{q} = k_b\vec{c}
$$ where 
$$
 k_b = \frac{\vec{b}\cdot \vec{c}}{|c|^2} =
$$
and for notational symmetry we write the $k$ given above as 
$$
 k_c = \frac{\vec{c}\cdot \vec{b}}{|b|^2} =
$$
Line $BQ$ is described by $\vec{b} + \alpha (\vec q - \vec{b}) $ and line $CP$ is described by $\vec{c} + \beta (\vec p - \vec{c}) $. Setting these equal, we have:
$$\begin{array}{l}
\alpha\vec{q} + (1-\alpha)\vec{b} = \beta\vec{p} + (1-\beta)\vec{c} \\
\alpha k_b \vec{c} + (1-\alpha)\vec{b} = \beta k_c \vec{b} + (1-\beta)\vec{c} \\
(1-\alpha - \beta k_b) \vec{b} = (1-\beta - \alpha k_c) \vec{c}
\end{array}
$$
and since $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are not linearly dependent, this can only be true if 
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
1-\alpha - \beta k_b = 0\\
1-\beta - \alpha k_c =0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
then
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\alpha = \frac{1-k_b}{1-k_c}\\
\beta = \frac{1-k_c}{1-k_b}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
so the orthocenter is at 
$$
\vec{b} + \alpha (\vec q - \vec{b}) =
\vec{b} + \frac{1-k_b}{1-k_c}(k_b\vec{c} - \vec{b})
$$
On the computer you calculate $k_b$ and $k_c$ and then combine in this way.

The perpendicular bisector points are trivial in this scheme: On $AB$ the point is $\vec{b}/2$ for example.

The three perpendicular bisectors meet at the circumcenter.
At the circumcenter we are on the line from $\vec{c}$ to  $\vec{b}/2$ and also on the line from $\vec{b}$ to  $\vec{c}/2$ so
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\alpha \vec{c} + (1-\alpha)\vec{b}/2) = \beta \vec{b} + (1-\beta)\vec{c} \\
\left(
\alpha - \frac{1-\beta}{2}
\right) \vec{c}=
\left(
\beta - \frac{1-\alpha}{2}
\right) \vec{b}
\end{array}
$$
and as before, each of those coefficients must be zero so 
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\beta = \frac{1-\alpha}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2} + \alpha + \frac{1-\alpha}{4} = 0 \\
\alpha = \frac{1}{3}
\end{array}
$$
and the circumcenter is at 
$$
\frac{\vec{b}+\vec{c}}{3}
$$
The same sort of techniques work to find the other points.  Probably your professor wanted you to do these calculations as part of your project, so I won't finish it all for you. The hardest one will be the incenter, which is the intersection of the angle bisectors.